# Dynamically create return type

Tags: kotlin

I am really new to Kotlin and mostly coded in Javascript but I'm looking to see if I can dynamically create types while maintaining the static analysis.
This is what I'm looking to achieve.

```
    class TestOne {
     def one(){
       print('function one');
     }
    }

    class TestTwo {
     def two() {
       print('function two');
     }
    }

workItOut("TestOne").one() // prints "function one"
workItOut("TestTwo").two() // prints "function two"
```

The `workItOut` function will take the string and create the class

```
fun workItOut(name: String) {
        if(name.equals("TestOne"))
            return TestOne()
        else if(name.equals("TestTwo"))
            return TestTwo()

        return ""
    }
```

Comment: You can return a `TestOne()` or a `TestTwo()` dynamically however, you can't call `.one()` / `.two()` on the result because a statically typed language requires that it can ensure at compile time that these methods exist. You can return `Any` from `workItOut` but then only use methods that exist on `Any` which is pretty much nothing. Dynamically calling methods the compiler doesn't know of can only be achieved through reflection.

Comment: Or casting `(x as TestOne).one()`, i.e telling the compiler what type it is at your risk of being mistaken and getting a cast exception. It's best not to try to make a static language dynamic and vice versa, look for idiomatic solutions to your problem

Comment: Which Kotlin backend are you using? In the JS backend, you can use the special [`dynamic`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html) type to effectively disable type checking to allow code like what you have in your question.

Comment: I'm using Kotlin JVM

Answer (score 3):

The typesafe way to achieve what you want is:

```
interface DoSomething {
    fun foo()
}

class TestOne : DoSomething {
    override fun foo() {
        println("function one")
    }
}

class TestTwo : DoSomething {
    override fun foo() {
        println("function two")
    }
}

fun workItOut(name: String): DoSomething {
    return when (name) {
        "TestOne" -> TestOne()
        "TestTwo" -> TestTwo()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Invalid type identifier $name")
    }
}

workItOut("TestOne").foo()
workItOut("TestTwo").foo()
```

The non-typesafe (*and evil, non-kotlin, non-static typed*) way is to use an unsafe cast and tell the function what result you expect to have (you seem to know what to expect because you are calling `one()` versus `two()`):

```
class TestOne {
    fun one() {
        println("function one")
    }
}

class TestTwo {
    fun twpo {
        println("function two")
    }
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T: Any> workItOut(name: String): T {
    return when (name) {
        "TestOne" -> TestOne() as T
        "TestTwo" -> TestTwo() as T
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Invalid type identifier $name")
    }
}

workItOut<TestOne>("TestOne").one()
workItOut<TestTwo>("TestTwo").two()
```

Comment: Your first code needs an exhaustive `when`, otherwise you cannot return a value from it